# Vim, Java: Open class under cursor and go to method

Tags: java, vim, text-cursor, code-navigation

Vim can open a file under cursor using `gf`. For example, if I have the following under my cursor:

```
SensorManagementActivity.java
```

Hitting `gf` will open `SensorManagementActivity.java`.

The problem is that in Java, the references lack the `java` suffix, and often appear as `SomeClass`, `SomeClass()` or `SomeClass.method()`.

- How do I open `SomeClass.java` and jump to `someMethod()` when the cursor is on `SomeClass.someMethod()` in another file?
- Is there a way to open a new file without saving the current one, and going back to the current one without losing changes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `'suffixesadd'` option allows `gf` to handle Java file extensions; it is already set by the *java* filetype that ships with Vim, like this:

```
:setlocal suffixesadd=.java
```

To jump to methods, Vim can use a *tags* file that must be (re-)generated first (there are plugins that can automate that). For Java, you can use the *exuberant ctags* tool.

```
:! ctags -R
```

For more information and alternatives, read `:help ctags`. Use the `:tag` command or the Ctrl-] shortcut to jump.

You can jump to a split window via Ctrl-W ]. To be able to leave a modified file and return back to it later, `:set hidden` in your `~/.vimrc`.

<sup>PS: Though here they're kind of related, it's best to avoid asking multiple questions at Stack Overflow</sup>

Comment: +1 Thanks a lot for the answer. `:! ctags -R` does not work for me yet - trying to find a workaround.

Comment: You may have to install `ctags`, it is not included in Vim. Also, the non-exuberant plain version does not understand Java. You can also invoke it directly from the console; after a successful run, there should be a file named `tags` in the current directory.

Comment: `-R` is just for recursive processing of subdirectories, which is helpful, but not required. But I haven't come across an exuberant ctags that doesn't have that option, maybe you just have the plain ctags. Check the output of `ctags --help`, and install exuberant ctags (5.9 is current) if necessary.